# How to deal correctly witn Webpack and jQuery dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js, materialize

I have a project created based on [Vue CLI](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI) and addded [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) in the project. I changed my `webpack.dev.conf.js`, `webpack.prod.conf.js` and `webpack.base.conf.js` as follow (only the supppose relevant part):

**Dev and prod**:

```
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.$': 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
  ]
```

**Base:**

```
resolve: {
extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
alias: {
  '$': 'jquery',
  'jQuery': 'jquery',
  'window.$': 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',      
  '@': resolve('src'),
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
}
```

The `main.js` have this content:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
```

When I call `$('#modal').modal('open')`, after the initialization, I recieve the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery__(...).modal is not a function
at Object.displayLoading (eval at <anonymous> (0.js:278), <anonymous>:10:55)
at VueComponent.searchBCP (eval at <anonymous> (0.js:293), <anonymous>:107:63)
at boundFn (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:810), <anonymous>:125:14)
at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:810), <anonymous>:1659:18)
displayLoading @ display-loading.js?d781:6
searchBCP @ script.js?7493:104
boundFn @ vue.esm.js?65d7:124
invoker @ vue.esm.js?65d7:1658
```

My problem is also when I deal with VueJS directives and Materializecss, using the methods correctly. Has anyone ever faced this difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the proper import in the file that wants to refer to jquery
If you refer to `$` in `myfile.js`you should have in `main.js`:

```
require("imports-loader?$=jquery!./myfile.js");
```

Which will add to `myfile.js`:

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

See reference here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent jQuery from bundling and retrieve its dependency at runtime you can use the [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals) configuration in your webpack config file.

```
externals: {
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery",
  "window.jQuery": "jquery"
}
```